# Facebook and Google+ Sign-In

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode6, google-plus

I'm using both Google+ and Facebook in my app. 
My problem is that both of them require the OpenURL method in the appDelegate.

For Facebook login:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

For Google+ login:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

How can I use both google+ and facebook in the same app?

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510584/1077789)

Answer (score 6):

**Solution Updated for Xcode 7.0 and Swift 2.0**

```
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String, annotation: nil)  ||
            GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String, annotation: nil)
```

**

### **Swift 3.0** another solution

**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if url.scheme == "fb1675189366130133" {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                         open: url,
                                                         sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                         annotation: annotation)
        }else{
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, use this bit of code:

```
if url.scheme == "fb1111111111111" {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
} else {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```