# Facebook SDK login never calls back my application on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) guide to update my application to use Facebook SDK 4.6 to work properly when built with the iOS 9 SDK.

When I tap the login button now, a Safari view controller gets presented (shouldn't it redirect to the Facebook app?), but after accepting permission the Safari view controller is never dismissed. It loads a new blank page and sits there doing nothing. If I tap the Done button, the returned `FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult`'s `isCancelled` is true.

Is it normal that the SDK is choosing the Safari view controller over the Facebook app? And why am I not getting callbacks after login is complete?

Comment: Concerning redirection to app: there is a property called FBSDKLoginBehavior to set the login behavior (can be set to login through old school webview, system, or FB app). If you're frustrated about the default login being a SFSafariViewController join the club here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Turns out that on iOS 9 when `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `application:openURL:options:` is implemented, `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` will not get called.

So what I had to do is call `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`'s `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` from `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `application:openURL:options:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                   annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing the issue where SAFARI opens instead of APP. Is it a bug on FB's side, or I'm missing something (Although I'm getting callbacks from safari when login is successful)

Comment: Native login is disabled on iOS 9+. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CPqUE3bW8AEcS8n.png

Comment: In SDK v4.6 and v3.24, the FB SDK uses Safari View Controller by default rather than fast-app-switching to the native Facebook app. This is by design, and because on iOS 9, Safari View Controller offers a better experience for people than the fast-app-switch flow.

Comment: @HeshamAbd-Elmegid, is your `didFinishLaunching` method called? my accessToken is still nil. Can you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184856/didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-not-called-during-facebook-login-flow-ios-9)?

Comment: For those of you looking for the Swift solution, it can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33080849/1897596

Answer (score 32):

For Swift this was working for me (add it in AppDelegate.swift):

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, 
     openURL: url, 
     sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String,
     annotation: options [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

and

```
@available(iOS, introduced=8.0, deprecated=9.0)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {  
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
     openURL: url,
     sourceApplication: sourceApplication!,
     annotation: annotation)
}
```

In each case remember to add `import FBSDKCoreKit` with the other `import` statements.

Its basically what Google SignIn uses. If its still not working you need to set the delegates and your info.plist like it is specified in the FaceBook Docs. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

For Swift 3 & Facebook SDK 4.16.0:

Add the following code to AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For those of you experiencing this same issue with iOS10 I added this:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

This should work but as for now its just a workaround

Answer (score 3):

I have just come across this issue, thanks @Hesham for the fix.

Here is the Swift3 fix:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        app,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for xamarin users :

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
        {

            OnUrlProtocolDetected(url.ToString());
            if (url.AbsoluteString.StartsWith("fb"))
            {
                return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
            }

}
```

Comment: That's what we want! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow these steps?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
openURL:url
sourceApplication:sourceApplication
annotation:annotation
 ];
}
```

I think you are missing the point where you got to call the applications delegate in App delegate.
The second method is vital coz it gives the callback to your application about the login did finish in safari by the user

Comment: Yes I did. My app worked fine before I started building with iOS 9.

Comment: This method is deprecated from iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the **old 3.24** version and on `iOS 9` I was facing a similar problem.

Found that in `appDelegate` method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

**was**

`return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];`

**instead of**

`return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];`

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

For total swift newbies like myself, the problem was an alternate implementation of the application() method:

Working version:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

Non working version (Copied from somewhere )

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking for Swift assistance on this very issue the following worked for me.

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey, annotation: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey)
    }
```