# Facebook login with iOS 9 involves a blank screen

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I own a Ionic/Cordova application running on IOS 9.

I pushed the new 3.24.1 Facebook SDK that I referenced using this [Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Facebook) for Cordova; this one being called by [ngCordova](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/).

Login appears on browser as stated by IOS 9 guidelines, but as soon as the person is logged in successfully through Facebook, the mechanism doesn't redirect to my app.
**Instead I end up with this full blank screen **:

[image]

**I have to click on "Ok" (or "Done" for english) to return to my app.**

Has anyone just experienced the same scenario?

Is it a current bug of concerned plugins?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299271/facebook-sdk-login-never-calls-back-my-application-on-ios-9  Solved the problem (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current solution was to revert back to SDK 3.21.X and disabling "Enable Bitcode" on project configuration.

Answer (score -1):

did  you update the `.plist` file in your app?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

from facebook documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: I instead put `<dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>` to get rid of those limitations (during test) but I think it's not related to the OP issue.  Indeed, if this was the case (due to those `dict` elements, I guess I would not be able to log the user).