# FBSDKLoginManager web dailog not dismissing after login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I'm trying to log into facebook using:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

After the login is successful, the web dailog should be dismissed automatially.But it is not happening.It stays on this screen:

[image]

And the strange thing is that , when I click on Done button in the web dailog, the result status `result.isCancelled` is displayed as `YES` even after the login is successful and also the `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is nil.

**Edit:** I'm able to do the login and get the token via `loginBehaviour FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` but not through NativeBehaviour

*I implemented every step mentioned in the Facebook SDK Developers page.*

Comment: FBSDKLoginKit is opensource. Happy debugging! Dive in and find the problem

Comment: I found my answer in here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299271/facebook-sdk-login-never-calls-back-my-application-on-ios-9, hence voted to close this question.