# How to use both google+ and facebook login in same appdelegate.swift

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift2, google-plus

My app use google+ signin and in my appdelegate.swift i have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true

}


func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Now i would like to insert also facebook login, but i have to add in appdelegate.swift this code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

But this return error because the functions 'application' already exist, how can I perform both google+ and facebook same appdelegate.swift
Thank you.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your application should handle facebook `and` google links, then return `true` if one `or` the other can handle the given link.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

        let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

        return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}
```

And in `didFinishLaunching` :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

Answer (score 14):

In Swift 3, need to do in this way:

Override and implement the next method:

```
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    let sourceApplication =  options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
    let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]

    let googleHandler = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
        url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation )

    let facebookHandler = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application (
        app,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation )

    return googleHandler || facebookHandler
}
```

Then:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(String(describing: configureError))")

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 5 you can do it this way:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your_client_id"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handledFB = FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    let handledGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    return handledFB || handledGoogle
}
```