# Is it possible to support both Facebook and Google login in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-plus-signin

I had success with authenticating with google plus, and also had success with authenticating with facebook.

But when I add both of them, google plus stops working and after pressing allow in this page

[image: img1]

, it goes back to google...

[image: img2]

```
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication: String?,annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    print("OPENURL_sourceApplication")
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation) ||
}
```

what should I "OR" in the return of the mentioned function?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510410/how-to-use-both-google-and-facebook-login-in-same-appdelegate-swift

Comment: thanks, solved, searched a lot and never known that question even existed.