# How to avoid the error invalid redeclaration in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I had integrated Braintree PayPal and google signin integration then I had implemented code in app delegate class but the both code have same functions and showing error that `Invalid redeclaration of 'application(_:open:options:)'` can anyone help me how to avoid this ?

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Braintree
import GoogleSignIn
//import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        BTAppSwitch.setReturnURLScheme("com.ewallsolutions.basic.Gometoo.payments")
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.ewallsolutions.basic.Gometoo.payments") == .orderedSame {
            return BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)
        }
        return false
    }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                        annotation: [:])
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name
            let email = user.profile.email
            let userImageURL = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 200)

        }
        else
        {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
                withError error: NSError!)
    {
        print("user disconnected")
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510410/how-to-use-both-google-and-facebook-login-in-same-appdelegate-swift\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write the same method twice. So, you can write this way.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        let braintreeHandle = false
        if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.ewallsolutions.basic.Gometoo.payments") == .orderedSame {
            braintreeHandle = BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)
        }

        let googleHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                                annotation: [:])
        return braintreeHandle || googleHandle
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have used open url method twice. Remove one method and use below code to avoid this error:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

        if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.ewallsolutions.basic.Gometoo.payments") == .orderedSame {
            return BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)

        } else {

            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                        annotation: [:])
        }
    }
```