# SDKApplicationDelegate Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I have two pods installed for facebook login

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

than imported FacebookCore in appdelegate. still it shows use of unresolved identifier error.

[image: unresolved identifier error]

I have also implemented tags in info.plist

```
<array>
<string>fb---------</string>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>-----------</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>-----------</string>
```

Still not able to get SDKApplicationDelegate.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
    if SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: instead of the answer, your question solved my issue, thank you : )

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Its because `SDKApplicationDelegate` is changed to `ApplicationDelegate`

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
    if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

One more thing to do

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

Also import these two pods

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

Comment: The error I get with this is ... Use of unresolved identifier 'ApplicationDelegate'; did you mean 'UIApplicationDelegate'? Replace 'ApplicationDelegate' with 'UIApplicationDelegate'

Comment: This return statement will work for all app switching? I have google, linkedIn, facebook. so this will work just for facebook or all of them?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala....yes please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510410/how-to-use-both-google-and-facebook-login-in-same-appdelegate-swift

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure why facebook have not there quick start guide lines

Answer (score 12):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8)
- Swift 5
- FacebookCore (0.7.0)

### Solution

just replace `SDKApplicationDelegate` with `ApplicationDelegate`

### Code

```
import FacebookCore

//....

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

//....

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    guard let urlScheme = url.scheme else { return false }
    if urlScheme.hasPrefix("fb") {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This works as stated with swift 5 as of July 2019. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to have facebook login add these 2 methods

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,open url: URL,options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL?, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

---

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

import FBSDKLoginKit
```

Comment: with this the error is: Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'; did you mean 'UIApplicationDelegate'? Replace 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate' with 'UIApplicationDelegate'

Comment: Importing will convert the code same as above answer. so this worked.